# Fastest way to search for contents of files

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I'm doing a search for specific text in web files. The user enters the text. There are about 850 files I have to search. The code below accomplishes what I want but it takes about 11-13 seconds. This code is in a web service I call from a web page using $.ajax GET. Is there a way I can improve the code so the search goes faster? Or should I be looking at other areas instead of my code?

I do the replaces in the document because of how the files are created (they create web files using MS Word...another battle) and it improves my search results.

```
var searchResults = new StringBuilder();

var parameters = searchParameters.Split('|');

var searchOnCompletePhrase = bool.Parse(parameters[1]);

var completePhrasePattern = @"\b(?:" + Regex.Escape(parameters[0].ToString()) + @")\b";

var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.htm");

if (searchOnCompletePhrase && searchPhrase.Length > 1)
{
    foreach (var currentFile in files)
    {
        document.Load(currentFile);

        contents = document.DocumentNode.InnerText.Replace("\r", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
            .Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty)
            .Replace("  ", " ");

        if (contents.ToLower().IndexOf(searchPhrase.ToLower()) > -1)
        {
            searchResults.AppendLine(currentFile);

            searchResults.Append("|");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    var keywords = parameters[0].Split(' ');

    foreach (var currentFile in files)
    {
        document.Load(currentFile);

        contents = document.DocumentNode.InnerText.Replace("\r", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
            .Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty)
            .Replace("  ", " ");

        var found = true;

        foreach (var word in keywords)
        {
            if (!SearchCurrentWord(word.ToString()))
            {
                found = false;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            searchResults.AppendLine(currentFile);

            searchResults.Append("|");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to profile your code to understand where time is spent. There is a very good chance that insanely wasteful code that creates huge amount of unused strings shown in the post does not really matter as it still need to spend the same time actually reading files. (On top of the fact Word is not supported on servers - so may or may not work at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try Parallel.Foreach instead of foreach loop to avoid waiting every file from disk sequentially.

Comment: You know, I forgot about Parallel.Foreach. I'll try that.

Comment: Please inform me about result.

Comment: That cut my search down to 8 seconds. Thank you.